# Visual Studio Code keeps discovering python interpreters forever and vscode-server on remote is busy 100%

Tags: visual-studio-code

When openning a folder using remote ssh in Visual Studio code with Python extension of Microsoft, the "discovering python interpreters" goes on forever. On the remote (ubuntu), it can be observed that vscode-server is taking 100% of the CPU. Also, the Python extension functionality is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the openned directory there is a sub directory that contains many files (millions). This is for a good reason. Still, the vscode server keeps searching through these files for potential Python environments, and this takes forever.

Moving this sub directory to a different location solved the problem.